# why pUnkInner can call QueryInterface in COM's aggregation?

Tags: com, aggregation

When I learn COM's aggregation, I know that `COuterclass::pUnkInner` points to `CInnerclass::INondelegationUnknown` interface, while `CInnerclass::QueryInterface`  doesn't belong to `INondelegationUnknown`, so why `pUnkInner` can call `QueryInterface` , for example, `pUnkInner->QueryInterface`.

Comment: You can *always* call QueryInterface on an interface pointer.  The detail you probably missed is that INondelegationUnknown derives from IUnknown, like all COM interfaces do.  And therefore inherits the three IUnknown methods.  We can't see it from here but it is the normal way.

Comment: From where are you learning COM?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `INondelegationUnknown` is - that's not part of COM, probably specific to the framework you are using.

But the key part is, one way or the other the inner object of the aggregation must provide two distinct implementations of `IUnknown`. One is a delegating implementation - it forwards all calls to `IUnknown` pointer provided by the outer in `CoCreateInstance`, when the aggregation relationship was first established. All interfaces exposed by the inner must implement their three `IUnknown` methods this way. Outer hands those interfaces out to external clients - by delegating to the outer, the illusion of a single seamless object is maintained.

The other `IUnknown` implementation manages the reference count and exposes interfaces implemented by the inner object itself (like a regular COM object) - that's the non-delegating implementation, one that the outer class uses to manage the inner. It's never exposed externally. The outer uses this non-delegating pointer in its own `QueryInterface` implementation to obtain interfaces implemented by the inner (and then hand them out to clients), as well as to release the inner eventually.